# openssl on Arm/linux no response when use genrsa

Tags: linux, openssl, arm

I use openssl1.1.1t, cross compile on raspberry pi. The cross compile chain is arm-linux-gnueabihf, Target platform is linux-aarch64.

Then use Configure, Make, make install.
opy the installed folder to my Arm64 environment. When I enter the following command, the version information can be displayed correctly.

```
#openssl version
OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
```

First I want make a test but error:

```
#openssl speed rsa
RSA sign failure.  No RSA sign will be done. 
4159107088:error:0306E06C:bignum routines:BN_mod_inverse:no inverse:crypto/bn/bn_gcd.c:532:  
RSA verify failure.  No RSA verify will be done. 
4159107088:error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length:crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c:132: 
OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023 built on: Tue Mar  7 11:20:11 2023 UTC 
options:bn(32,32) rc4(char) des(long) aes(partial) idea(int) blowfish(ptr) 
compiler: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fPIC -pthread -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DNDEBUG
```

I searched for a solution and tried to use this command, but I don't understand what's going on:

```
# strace openssl speed rsa
execve("/usr/bin/openssl", ["openssl", "speed", "rsa"], 0x7fc5461da0 /* 32 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=8126 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
brk(NULL)                               = 0x452000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="M3568", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
fstat64(3, 0xfff119a8)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 29539, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xf7e52000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib32/libssl.so.1.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0004\n\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xfff119e0)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7e50000
mmap2(NULL, 525496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7db2000
mprotect(0xf7e1a000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7e2a000, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x68000) = 0xf7e2a000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib32/libcrypto.so.1.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\250t\4\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xfff119d0)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 2117540, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7bad000
mprotect(0xf7d88000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7d97000, 98304, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1da000) = 0xf7d97000
mmap2(0xf7daf000, 12196, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7daf000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib32/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\230\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xfff119c0)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73916, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7b9a000
mprotect(0xf7b9c000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7bab000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xf7bab000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib32/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\305M\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xfff119b0)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 148072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7b75000
mprotect(0xf7b87000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7b96000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0xf7b96000
mmap2(0xf7b98000, 4712, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7b98000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib32/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0Iw\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xfff119a0)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 996012, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7a81000
mprotect(0xf7b5f000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7b6f000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xde000) = 0xf7b6f000
mmap2(0xf7b72000, 8876, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7b72000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7e4e000
set_tls(0xf7e4e4d0, 0xf7e4ebc0, 0xf7e5c060, 0xf7e4e4d0, 0xf7e5c060) = 0
mprotect(0xf7b6f000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7b96000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7bab000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7d97000, 90112, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0xf7e2a000, 20480, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0x9f000, 4096, PROT_READ)      = 0
mprotect(0xf7e5b000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xf7e52000, 29539)               = 0
set_tid_address(0xf7e4e078)             = 8126
set_robust_list(0xf7e4e080, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0xf7b7995d, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xf7aa7a01}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0xf7b799e1, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xf7aa7a01}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x452000
brk(0x473000)                           = 0x473000
futex(0xf7db0ac4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0ac8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0acc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0a34, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0xf7aa79f1}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0   
futex(0xf7db0b70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0ad4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0ad8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0ae8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7dae404, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7dae990, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7dae48c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0ad0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7db0aec, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/root/arm-openssl/openssl-1.1.1t/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY|0x20000) = 3
fstat64(3, 0xfff11d68)                  = 0
read(3, "#\n# OpenSSL example configuratio"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "# WARNING: ancient versions of N"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "es of the usage of nsCertType. I"..., 4096) = 2717
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0xf7db0adc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7e32498, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
sysinfo({uptime=89409, loads=[768, 4552558683193495552, 129302567426969600], totalram=0, freeram=4158783677, sharedram=4294967296, bufferram=17862111806687084544, totalswap=17847587623156250700, freeswap=17862112906198579404, procs=8012, totalhigh=18446744073573565120, freehigh=17845728684137250817, mem_unit=4158982880}) = 0
futex(0xf7e324b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGALRM, {sa_handler=0x53c80, sa_mask=[ALRM], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0xf7aa79f1}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0   
futex(0xf7db0bb0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
getpid()                                = 8126
getrandom("\x3a\xf3\x7e\x76\xc1\xd6\xee\xd2\x4d\x89\x6a\x12\x52\x9c\xe4\x57\xf3\xa1\x63\x2b\xe5\xfd\xf0\x26\xac\x44\xda\x74\x1c\xe6\x4b\xe7", 32, 0) = 32
getpid()                                = 8126
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {tv_sec=3063982185486221227, tv_nsec=17862648381382336446}) = 0
gettimeofday({tv_sec=3065002009821099, tv_usec=17856275182495651272}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xf7db0b98, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
getpid()                                = 8126
getpid()                                = 8126
gettimeofday({tv_sec=3067347061964715, tv_usec=17856284236286711240}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({tv_sec=3068163105750955, tv_usec=17856275182495652840}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8126
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=1084880950531284288, tv_nsec=17862648381382336446}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8126
gettimeofday({tv_sec=3070009941688235, tv_usec=17856284236286712808}, NULL) = 0
write(2, "RSA sign failure.  No RSA sign w"..., 45RSA sign failure.  No RSA sign will be done.
) = 45
write(2, "4158971920:error:0306E06C:bignum"..., 924158971920:error:0306E06C:bignum routines:BN_mod_inverse:no inverse:crypto/bn/bn_gcd.c:532:
) = 92
write(2, "RSA verify failure.  No RSA veri"..., 49RSA verify failure.  No RSA verify will be done.
) = 49
write(2, "4158971920:error:04091077:rsa ro"..., 1044158971920:error:04091077:rsa routines:int_rsa_verify:wrong signature length:crypto/rsa/rsa_sign.c:132:
) = 104
getpid()                                = 8126
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=1090817471507684672, tv_nsec=17862648381382336446}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8126
gettimeofday({tv_sec=3076181809692587, tv_usec=17856284236286712808}, NULL) = 0
fstat64(1, 0xfff10608)                  = 0
write(1, "OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023\n", 27OpenSSL 1.1.1t  7 Feb 2023
) = 27
write(1, "built on: Tue Mar  7 11:20:11 20"..., 39built on: Tue Mar  7 11:20:11 2023 UTC
) = 39
write(1, "options:bn(32,32) rc4(char) des("..., 76options:bn(32,32) rc4(char) des(long) aes(partial) idea(int) blowfish(ptr)
) = 76
write(1, "compiler: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gc"..., 105compiler: arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc -fPIC -pthread -Wall -O3 -DOPENSSL_USE_NODELETE -DOPENSSL_PIC -DNDEBUG
) = 105
exit_group(0)                           = ?
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

The difference is that using the genrsa command did not cause an error, but was suspended. Using strace found an infinite loop.

```
# strace openssl genrsa 2048 > ca-key.pem
execve("/usr/bin/openssl", ["openssl", "genrsa", "2048"], 0x7fd2184960 /* 32 vars */) = 0
strace: [ Process PID=8307 runs in 32 bit mode. ]
brk(NULL)                               = 0x16d3000
uname({sysname="Linux", nodename="M3568", ...}) = 0
access("/etc/ld.so.preload", R_OK)      = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
fstat64(3, 0xff85aa08)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 29539, PROT_READ, MAP_PRIVATE, 3, 0) = 0xf7e84000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib32/libssl.so.1.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0004\n\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xff85aa40)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7e82000
mmap2(NULL, 525496, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7de4000
mprotect(0xf7e4c000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7e5c000, 36864, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x68000) = 0xf7e5c000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/lib32/libcrypto.so.1.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\250t\4\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xff85aa30)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 2117540, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7bdf000
mprotect(0xf7dba000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7dc9000, 98304, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1da000) = 0xf7dc9000
mmap2(0xf7de1000, 12196, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7de1000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib32/libdl.so.2", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\230\t\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xff85aa20)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 73916, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7bcc000
mprotect(0xf7bce000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7bdd000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x1000) = 0xf7bdd000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib32/libpthread.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0\305M\0\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xff85aa10)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 148072, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7ba7000
mprotect(0xf7bb9000, 61440, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7bc8000, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0x11000) = 0xf7bc8000
mmap2(0xf7bca000, 4712, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7bca000
close(3)                                = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib32/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC|0x20000) = 3
read(3, "\177ELF\1\1\1\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\3\0(\0\1\0\0\0Iw\1\0004\0\0\0"..., 512) = 512
fstat64(3, 0xff85aa00)                  = 0
mmap2(NULL, 996012, PROT_READ|PROT_EXEC, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0) = 0xf7ab3000
mprotect(0xf7b91000, 65536, PROT_NONE)  = 0
mmap2(0xf7ba1000, 12288, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_DENYWRITE, 3, 0xde000) = 0xf7ba1000
mmap2(0xf7ba4000, 8876, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_FIXED|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7ba4000
close(3)                                = 0
mmap2(NULL, 8192, PROT_READ|PROT_WRITE, MAP_PRIVATE|MAP_ANONYMOUS, -1, 0) = 0xf7e80000
set_tls(0xf7e804d0, 0xf7e80bc0, 0xf7e8e060, 0xf7e804d0, 0xf7e8e060) = 0
mprotect(0xf7ba1000, 8192, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7bc8000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7bdd000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
mprotect(0xf7dc9000, 90112, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0xf7e5c000, 20480, PROT_READ)  = 0
mprotect(0x9f000, 4096, PROT_READ)      = 0
mprotect(0xf7e8d000, 4096, PROT_READ)   = 0
munmap(0xf7e84000, 29539)               = 0
set_tid_address(0xf7e80078)             = 8307
set_robust_list(0xf7e80080, 12)         = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRTMIN, {sa_handler=0xf7bab95d, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xf7ad9a01}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGRT_1, {sa_handler=0xf7bab9e1, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART|SA_SIGINFO, sa_restorer=0xf7ad9a01}, NULL, 8) = 0
rt_sigprocmask(SIG_UNBLOCK, [RTMIN RT_1], NULL, 8) = 0
ugetrlimit(RLIMIT_STACK, {rlim_cur=8192*1024, rlim_max=RLIM_INFINITY}) = 0
brk(NULL)                               = 0x16d3000
brk(0x16f4000)                          = 0x16f4000
futex(0xf7de2ac4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2ac8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2acc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2a34, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
rt_sigaction(SIGPIPE, {sa_handler=SIG_IGN, sa_mask=[PIPE], sa_flags=SA_RESTORER|SA_RESTART, sa_restorer=0xf7ad99f1}, {sa_handler=SIG_DFL, sa_mask=[], sa_flags=0}, 8) = 0   
futex(0xf7de2b70, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2ad4, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2ad8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2ae8, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de0404, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de0990, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de048c, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2ad0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7de2aec, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/root/arm-openssl/openssl-1.1.1t/openssl.cnf", O_RDONLY|0x20000) = 3
fstat64(3, 0xff85adc8)                  = 0
read(3, "#\n# OpenSSL example configuratio"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "# WARNING: ancient versions of N"..., 4096) = 4096
read(3, "es of the usage of nsCertType. I"..., 4096) = 2717
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
futex(0xf7de2adc, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
futex(0xf7e64498, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
sysinfo({uptime=89635, loads=[0, 4550623542728609792, 129408120543322112], totalram=0, freeram=4159045822, sharedram=4294967296, bufferram=17862991415989510144, totalswap=17848467232458676300, freeswap=17862992515501005004, procs=44972, totalhigh=18446744073573769920, freehigh=17846608293439471617, mem_unit=4159187680}) = 0
futex(0xf7e644b0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
write(2, "Generating RSA private key, 2048"..., 61Generating RSA private key, 2048 bit long modulus (2 primes)
) = 61
futex(0xf7de2bb0, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
getrandom("\x7f\x7a\x59\xb3\x47\x02\x6f\xdf\x6f\xc6\xfd\xd7\x97\x2b\x52\x25\x66\x55\xba\x22\x74\xc4\xfa\x62\x4f\x5f\x57\xe5\x66\x48\x99\x49", 32, 0) = 32
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_REALTIME, {tv_sec=1630773039287763086, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1631621099290766, tv_usec=17857154791817230328}, NULL) = 0
futex(0xf7de2b98, FUTEX_WAKE_PRIVATE, 2147483647) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1633738518167694, tv_usec=17857163845608290296}, NULL) = 0
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1634507317313678, tv_usec=17857154791817235024}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=3946183116539911714, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1636422872727694, tv_usec=17857163845608294992}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=3959590715947834914, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1649956314677390, tv_usec=17857163845608294992}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=3973466823273307682, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1663798994272398, tv_usec=17857163845608294992}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=3986910753809587746, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1677152047595662, tv_usec=17857163845608294992}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=4000036495988710946, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1690247402881166, tv_usec=17857163845608294992}, NULL) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME, {tv_sec=4014660464494599714, tv_nsec=17863527990684557427}) = 0
getpid()                                = 8307
gettimeofday({tv_sec=1706396479914126, tv_usec=17857163845608294992}, NULL) = 0
....The following are the same repetition
```

I also searched a lot of information on the Internet, but to no avail, can anyone give me some advice.

This is configure when setup.

`./Configure linux-aarch64 no-asm shared --prefix="/root/arm-openssl/openssl" --openssldir="/root/arm-openssl/openssl-1.1.1t" --cross-compile-prefix="arm-linux-gnueabihf-"`

Here is raspberrypi systeminfo.

`Linux 4.19.66-v7+ #1253 SMP Thu Aug 15 11:49:46 BST 2019 unknown unknown GNU/Linux`

Here is Arm systeminfo.

`Linux M3568 4.19.193 #3 SMP Tue Feb 7 01:36:58 PST 2023 aarch64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: *"no response when using genrsa"* . Does it work with anything else? Also, please include more info about how you setup your `configure && make` . output from `uname -ioprsv` from both systems? Good luck.

Comment: `arm-*-gcc` would be a compiler targeting 32-bit ARM.  To target aarch64 your cross-compiler should be `aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc` or similar.  In this ecosystem, `arm` by itself (including `armhf` and such) always indicates 32-bit.  64-bit is denoted by `arm64` or `aarch64`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem. I followed Nate Eldredge's suggestion and changed the platform to linux-armv4. Then I copied the libc.so and other files on the Arm to the Raspberry Pi and recompiled openssl.